# Travelling (domestically) to my family during the pandemic?

Tags: uk, covid-19, pandemics

With places going on lock down, I am concerned about my options should things become unsafe.

I am a student renting a room in one of the cities in the UK, a few hours away from London by car. My family lives in London. I am concerned about a complete lock down being implemented as I don't know if travelling to my family would be considered necessary travel, even if there start being reports of people breaking into houses. For obvious reasons, if this starts happening I would like to be as close to my family as possible. Right now, with universities still insisting that coursework and exams will be take place (even if remotely), moving back with my family would essentially be sabotaging myself due to issues at home to the point where I might fail university just like I failed my A-Levels, and this is my last year.

What are the chances that I won't be able to travel/move in back with my family during the next few months?

Comment: Lockdowns mean stay in place. Wherever you are, don’t move. There is a definite possibility you may already be carrying the virus, and you don’t want to spread it any further, and certainly not infect people who are more likely to suffer adverse consequences if they get infected.

Comment: @Lukali I’d say tonight’s order from the Prime Minister means you already can’t travel to your family https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155250/is-travelling-with-1-friend-permitted-in-the-uk-now-that-the-lockdown-is-enforce IMHO it would only be essential if you were no longer renting where you are now and had no alternative but to return to your family (and self-isolate for 7 days after arrival).

Comment: Welcome to TSE, but I'm afraid "what are the chances" questions are inherently speculative, especially considering that the current crisis is utterly unprecedented. You are not the only one facing difficult choices like this, and I do wish you the best of luck.

Comment: If roving gangs of zombies start breaking into houses, and for some reason you think using public transit to try to get to London is safer than staying in the house that might get broken into, I expect lockdown orders will be widely breached and you won't care if they've been lifted or not. That said, I don't even think the first thing will happen - and if it does, leaving will not be a safe choice. Stay where you are, keep your germs to yourself and focus on dealing with the current situation, not an imaginary worse one.

Comment: > nasty virus running around > being close to others spreads it > want to be as close to family as possible

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I don't live alone either, so its either being close to family or strangers who I know nothing about...

Comment: It is hard to tell whether you want to be safe with your family for safety, or stay where you are to pass your exams. It's understandable that you are worried by the situation, but we all are. Mr Johnson has announced today: no travel, stay at home, and home means where you are now.